# Xamarin android set image in ImageView from php web hosting

Tags: c#, php, android, xamarin

Simply when I put an image-url in my c# Xamarin android code

```
var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(mydata["newsimage1"].ToString());
imageView1.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

from a website like blogger it works and the application view it without any problems.

For example this image url:

> http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-_PdNK07R8wQ/VzdAiJtOdqI/AAAAAAAABLE/AzxlzGVbL_Y5HCKH3ckGtEr7pwkKvhaJQCK4B/s1600/2.png

It works fine, but when I put an image that uploaded into my php webhost 
it does not  work!

For example this url:

> www.ihled.eb2a.com/gcmt/NewsImages/170108022726.jpg

Anyone have any idea about that ?

Comment: you need to look at the detailed http response from both cases and see where they differ.  Your local host is probably not setting the correct content header, or something like that.

Comment: it response the image-url correctly I think it's maybe because of Image Dir permissions something like that ! any new ideas ? but i don't know how to solve it is this possible ?

Comment: Did you add `http://` in front of `www.ihled.eb2a.com/gcmt/NewsImages/170108022726.jpg`?

Comment: i had tried in both of http:// - or without http://